# Using ENVs for values in Kubernetes manifest file

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm laying the foundation for a new project where we will have an application running on Google Kubernetes Engine with multiple environments (development, staging, production). Each environment is its own GC Project.

I'm writing some manifest files and I'd like to abstract out any environment specific values so it can be re-used depending what environment (project) were updating/deploying to.

I have created values in Kubernetes Secrets, and turning those into ENV's is straight forward (see `DATABASE_URL`). However, if I wanted to use a variable for the value of the container image: `gcr.io/my-app-production-123:latest`, how would I pass in the value from a secret?

Is this the correct approach to abstracting environment specific values from manifest files? Thank you!

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: db-migrate
spec:
  completions: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: db-migrate
    spec:
      restartPolicy: Never
      containers:
      - name: db-migrate
        # how can I reference secret/env for the value of image:?
        image: gcr.io/my-app-production-242920:latest
        args: ["bundle", "exec", "rake", "db:create", "db:migrate"]
        env:
        - name: DATABASE_URL
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: app-secrets
              key: DATABASE_URL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to use a higher-level tool to inject variables like this.  The one I'm familiar with is [Helm](https://helm.sh) but there are other tools that let you inject parameters into the YAML files as well.

You can't use secrets the way you're describing.  The only things you can do with secrets (or config maps, they're very similar) are to [mount them as files](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/#create-a-pod-that-has-access-to-the-secret-data-through-a-volume) or use them to [set environment variables](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/distribute-credentials-secure/#define-container-environment-variables-using-secret-data).  You can, to a limited extent, [use environment variables to define other parts of the config](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/#using-environment-variables-inside-of-your-config); but if you look at [the API reference for containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.14/#container-v1-core) the places where the `$(VARIABLE)` syntax is allowed are specifically called out, and it is only allowed for `args:`, `command:`, and `env:`.

In Helm you can use Go's templating syntax in your YAML files, and so could write

```
image: gcr.io/my-app-production:{{ .Values.tag }}
```

and then deploy the service with something like

```
helm install ./my-app --set tag=242920
```

but I'm pretty sure there's not a way to parameterize pods (or deployments or statefulsets or ...) in plain unadorned Kubernetes.

Comment: Thank you. I had a tab opened here to investigate Helm. It kinda felt like my approach wasn't the correct way, but I'm still familiarizing myself with the tools for managing a multi-environment kubernetes application

Answer (score 0):

You can mount your secret inside the container and use it, [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#using-secrets).

Example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: mypod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: db-migrate
    image: gcr.io/my-app-production-242920:latest
    args: ["bundle", "exec", "rake", "db:create", "db:migrate"]
    volumeMounts:
    - name: <these_names_are_same>
      mountPath: "/container/where/to/mount"
      readOnly: true
  volumes:
  - name: <these_names_are_same>
    secret:
      secretName: <your deployed secret name>
```

Comment: Thank you. One thing I'm unclear about is providing a mount path. In my current config I just specify the gcr.io url to my container for the `image:` . I'm unclear what I would put for the mountPath

Comment: what you specify for `image:` is the docker image that you will use/ pull. But you define the specifications for that image. Edited my answer to include your requirement.